How can I make lookups in c++ as fast as possible?
I'm trying to create a chess bot. I'm using bit-boards to represent the board and pieces. I read online from several sources that using PEXT for sliding piece lookups makes your code really fast. I implemented my own version of it, and it's actually around 25% slower than my original implementation (which calculated each attack pattern with logical operations).
This is the new code which uses PEXT to calculate the attack pattern:
uint64_t Move_lookup::get_rook_moves(int index, uint64_t all_pieces) {
    int index2 = _pext_u64(all_pieces, rook_masks[index]);
    return rook_moves[index][index2];
}

My lookup table is a two dimensional vector. The first index is the starting index of the piece, and the second index is the specific attack pattern depending on the locations of other pieces. This index is obtained with PEXT. This is how I define my lookup table:
std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> rook_moves;
And this was my original implementation (Not currently used):
uint64_t Board::get_rook_moves(uint64_t* b, pieceColour colour, int n) {
    // We must perform the operation on the set the function was called with
    uint64_t rooks = *b;
    isolate_piece(&rooks, n); // This gets rid of all the 1's we are not interested in in rooks
    
    // Get all enemy pieces
    uint64_t enemy_pieces = all_pieces(invert_colour(colour));
    
    // Combined pieces for obstacle detection
    uint64_t black_white_pieces = all_pieces(colour) | enemy_pieces;
    
    uint64_t attacks = 0ULL;
    
    // We need to look in all four straight directions (N,E,S,W) until we hit the edge of the board or another piece
    // North
    uint64_t move = rooks;
    while (move & NOT_RANK_8) {  // Continue while not on the last rank
        move <<= 8;  // Move one rank up
        if (move & black_white_pieces) {  // Stop if a piece is encountered
            if (move & enemy_pieces) attacks |= move;  // If enemy piece, include in attacks
            break;
        }
        attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
    }
    
    // East
    move = rooks;
    while (move & NOT_H_FILE) {  // Continue while not on the H file
        move >>= 1;  // Move one file right
        if (move & black_white_pieces) {  // Stop if a piece is encountered
            if (move & enemy_pieces) attacks |= move;  // If enemy piece, include in attacks
            break;
        }
        attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
    }
    
    // South
    move = rooks;
    while (move & NOT_RANK_1) {  // Continue while not on the first rank
        move >>= 8;  // Move one rank down
        if (move & black_white_pieces) {  // Stop if a piece is encountered
            if (move & enemy_pieces) attacks |= move;  // If enemy piece, include in attacks
            break;
        }
        attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
    }
    
    // West
    move = rooks;
    while (move & NOT_A_FILE) {  // Continue while not on the A file
        move <<= 1;  // Move one file left
        if (move & black_white_pieces) {  // Stop if a piece is encountered
            if (move & enemy_pieces) attacks |= move;  // If enemy piece, include in attacks
            break;
        }
        attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
    }
    
    return attacks;
}

This is the code for how I fill my rook attacks lookup table (Note that this only runs once, at the start):
void Move_lookup::fill_rook_moves() {
    uint64_t i = 1ULL;
    for (auto& mask : rook_masks) {

        int count = count_set(mask);
        std::vector<uint64_t> perms = bin_n_perms_asc(count); // Get all permutations of the bits
        std::vector<uint64_t> temp;

        for (const auto& perm : perms) {
            uint64_t blockers = _pdep_u64(perm, mask); // Put the permutations on to the blockers
            uint64_t attacks = 0ULL;

            // We need to look in all four straight directions (N,E,S,W) until we hit the edge of the board or a blocker
            // North
            uint64_t move = i;
            while (move & NOT_RANK_8) {  // Continue while not on the last rank
                move <<= 8;  // Move one rank up
                attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
                if (move & blockers) break;
            }

            // East
            move = i;
            while (move & NOT_A_FILE) {  // Continue while not on the A file
                move >>= 1;  // Move one file right
                attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
                if (move & blockers) break;
            }

            // South
            move = i;
            while (move & NOT_RANK_1) {  // Continue while not on the first rank
                move >>= 8;  // Move one rank down
                attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
                if (move & blockers) break;
            }

            // West
            move = i;
            while (move & NOT_H_FILE) {  // Continue while not on the H file
                move <<= 1;  // Move one file left
                attacks |= move;  // Add square to attacks
                if (move & blockers) break;
            }

            temp.push_back(attacks);
        }   

        rook_moves.push_back(temp);
        i <<= 1;
    }
}

The lookups are probably slow because the array which stores the values is huge - it has over 100000 elements, but then again, every implementation which uses PEXT for lookups needs a table of this size. (Edit - Every implementation which does not use size optimisations)
Does anyone know how I can speed up my lookups?
Thanks a lot,
Michael

Welcome to stackoverflow! (1) What exactly the profiler tells, where is the bottleneck? (2) Make sure you don't have unnecessary coping of the table while passing to/from functions; check with CPU profiler and heap profiler. (3) Show how lookup table is used (filled, etc.), use cases could give a clue for a better structure for this.

std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> rook_moves; is very cumbersome and won't do you any favors when it comes to performance. The size of the lookup tables should be known at compile time and you should be able to allocate enough space on stack to hold all the values, preferably in one dimensional array.

Also it seems like you might have bigger lookup tables than really necessary, as edge squares don't have to be considered for probing, since occupancy status on those does not matter for the attack patterns

@JaneDoe Thanks for your response, I'll try with the size at compile time, by the way, I do not consider the edge squares when probing.

@DamirTenishev Thanks for your response. I'll add my code for how I fill the lookup table to my post. I'll also check the other things you suggested.

You might also want to try to further optimize for memory and cache by compressing further using PEXT/PDEP. You could have a look here how to do that https://github.com/syzygy1/tb/blob/master/src/bmi2.h however keep in mind that depending on your CPU and cache different approaches might be faster/slower than on other computers.

See the section on memory locality here for an explanation of one of the reasons std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> rook_moves; is slow. In general, computers love to go in nice, predictable lines where related pieces of data are stored close to one another. Almost anything you can do to make sure that when the computer goes looking for data it finds the data that it's going to use in the near future at the same time will produce amazing performance improvements.

A chess board is just 8x8 thus a contiguous 1d array in char fits into a single L1 cache line (Even i7 cpu has 64 bytes L1 cache line. Multiple vectors would hit cache miss "a lot".

This talk of Herb Sutter helps a lot if you're interested in performance.

The available squares for every chess piece can be represented by a single std::bitset<64> or std:unit64_t, one bit per square. The square number can be stored as a std::unit8_t used as index into available squares. No need for large containers and dynamic allocation. A full chess position - including unmomved markers for for rooks and kings and newly long moved pawn - can be represented within 256 bytes. Each move can be compressed into 16bits - including peice, color, source, destination, captures and promotions. So a std::vector<std::uint16_t> can hold the move history.
